# Здравствуйте, хочу вывести в TableView список страхователей

Tags: java, javafx, hibernate

POJO класс ОСАГО

```
package entity;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "osago")
public class Osago {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "osago_series")
    private String osagoSeries;

    @Column(name = "osago_number")
    private int osagoNumber;

    @Column(name = "start_insurance")
    private Date startInsurance;

    @Column(name = "end_insurance")
    private Date endInsurance;

    @Column(name = "date_of_issue")
    private Date dateOfIssue;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "agent_id")
    private Agent agent;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "driver_to_osago",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "osago_id")
            },inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id")
    })
    Set<Driver> drivers = new HashSet<>();

    public  void addDriver(Driver driver){
        drivers.add(driver);

    }
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "calculator_id")
    private Calculator calculator;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Osago{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", osagoSeries='" + osagoSeries + '\'' +
                ", osagoNumber=" + osagoNumber +
                ", startInsurance=" + startInsurance +
                ", endInsurance=" + endInsurance +
                ", dateOfIssue=" + dateOfIssue +
                ", agent=" + agent +
                ", calculator=" + calculator +
                '}';
    }
}
```

POJO класс Driver

```
package entity;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "driver")
public class Driver {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "FLP")
    private String flp;

    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name = "birth_date")
    private Date birthDate;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private BigInteger phone;

    @Column(name = "passport_series")
    private String passportSeries;

    @Column(name = "passport_number")
    private int passportNumber;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "driver")
    Set<DrvLicense> drvLicense = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "driver_to_osago",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id")
            },inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "osago_id")
    })
    Set<Osago> osagos = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "drivers")
    Set<Pts> pts;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  flp;
    }
}
```

Попытка вывести страхователей

```
OsagoSeriesCell.setCellValueFactory(o -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(o.getValue().getOsagoSeries()));
        OsagoNumberCell.setCellValueFactory(o -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(o.getValue().getOsagoNumber()));
        OsagoStartInsurance.setCellValueFactory(o -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(o.getValue().getStartInsurance()));
        OsagoEndInsurance.setCellValueFactory(o -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(o.getValue().getEndInsurance()));
        OsagoCount.setCellValueFactory(o -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(o.getValue().getId()));
        OsagoInsurer.setCellValueFactory(o -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(o.getValue().getDrivers().iterator().next().getFlp()));
        OsagoTableView.setItems(osagoObservableList);
        OsagoTableView.setEditable(true);
```

Ошибка

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1862)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1729)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8889)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3856)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2584)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1586)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1607)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$IteratorProxy.next(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:887)
    at controls.MainPanelController.lambda$initialize$31(MainPanelController.java:934)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:593)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:578)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:646)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:469)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:120)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.updateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:539)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.<init>(TableRowSkinBase.java:159)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:213)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:897)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9547)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.applyCss(Node.java:9634)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1743)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1720)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1846)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(VirtualFlow.java:2758)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1239)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1207)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1214)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1214)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1214)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1214)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1214)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1214)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1214)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1214)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:576)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1750)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$2.preferredSize(Scene.java:393)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.preferredSize(SceneHelper.java:66)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1111)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1187)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1202)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:273)
    at controls.SignInController.signIn(SignInController.java:52)
    ... 57 more
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1586)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1607)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$IteratorProxy.next(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:887)
    at controls.MainPanelController.lambda$initialize$31(MainPanelController.java:934)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:593)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:578)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:646)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:469)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:120)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.updateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:539)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.<init>(TableRowSkinBase.java:159)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:213)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:897)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:63)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSS(ControlHelper.java:55)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:886)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:63)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSS(ControlHelper.java:55)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:886)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:63)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSS(ControlHelper.java:55)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:886)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9547)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9540)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:569)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2471)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:413)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:412)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:439)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:563)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:543)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:536)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:342)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1586)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1607)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$IteratorProxy.next(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:887)
    at controls.MainPanelController.lambda$initialize$31(MainPanelController.java:934)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:593)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:578)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:646)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:469)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:120)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.updateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:539)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.<init>(TableRowSkinBase.java:159)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:213)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:897)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:63)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSS(ControlHelper.java:55)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:886)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:63)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSS(ControlHelper.java:55)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:886)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:63)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSS(ControlHelper.java:55)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:886)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9547)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9540)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:569)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2471)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:413)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:412)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:439)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:563)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:543)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:536)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:342)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Service

```
   @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Osago> generateContract() {
        try(Session session = factory.openSession()){
            Query<Osago> query = session.createQuery("From Osago");
            return query.list();
        }
    }
```

Инициализация observableList

```
DAO<Osago,Integer> osagoIntegerDAO = new OsagoService(factory);
        List<Osago> osagoList = osagoIntegerDAO.generateContract();
        osagoObservableList.addAll(osagoList);
```

DAO

```
package dao;

import java.util.List;

public interface DAO <Entity, Key> {
    void create (Entity entity);
    void update (Entity entity);
    void delete (Entity entity);
    Entity readById(Key key);
    List<Entity> generateContract();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Если кому интересно, то проблему я решил таким образом.

```
OsagoInsurer.setCellValueFactory(o -> {List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                                                Set<Driver> driverSet = o.getValue().getDrivers();
                                                for (Driver driver : driverSet){
                                                list.add(driver.getFlp());}
                                                if (list.size() != 0){
                                                    return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(String.valueOf(list));
                                                }else {
                                                    return new SimpleObjectProperty<>("non");
                                                }
       });
```

### Или

Метод в классе ОСАГО

```
public ObservableList<String> getName(){
        Iterator<Driver> iterator = getDrivers().iterator();
        ObservableList<String> name = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            String FLP = iterator.next().getFlp();
            name.add(FLP);
        }
        return name;
    }
```

Колонка

```
 OsagoInsurer.setCellValueFactory(o -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(o.getValue().getName().toString()));
```